# is $\sum\limits _{n=1}^{\infty}\ln\left(\frac{\left(n+1\right)^{2}}{n\left(n+2\right)}\right)<\infty$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I don't know why but I'm having a hard time determining whether this series 
$$
\sum\limits _{n=1}^{\infty}\ln\left(\frac{\left(n+1\right)^{2}}{n\left(n+2\right)}\right)
$$
converges to a real limit.

I did try to break it down according to $\ln$ identities.
$$
\ln\left(\frac{\left(n+1\right)^{2}}{n\left(n+2\right)}\right)=\ln\left(\left(n+1\right)^{2}\right)-\ln\left(n\left(n+2\right)\right)=2\ln\left(n+1\right)-\ln n-\ln\left(n+2\right)
$$
and then tried to increase it to get to a series that converges to a real number:
$$
2\ln\left(n+1\right)-\ln n-\ln\left(n+2\right)\leq 2\ln\left(n+1\right)-\ln n-\ln\left(n+1\right)=\ln\left(n+1\right)-\ln n
$$
so $S_n$ will be like that
$$
S_n=\ln2-\ln1+\ln3-\ln2+\dots+\ln(n+1)-\ln n \\=\ln (n+1)-\ln1=\ln (n+1)
$$
and so $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=\infty$

I know this series does converge to a real number (Well according to Wolfram Alpha :) $\ $)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

> Theorem: Let $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^pu_n=A$. $$\sum u_n$$ converges if $p>1$ and $A$ is finite.

Now take $p=2$.

Comment: Babak S:▄▀▄▀▄▒▒N▒i▒c▒e▒▒h▒i▒n▒t▒▒▄▀▄▀▄

Comment: Nice work, Babak! Nice work, you too, @flashdesign2550 ;-)

Comment: Thank you(◕ ‿-) `,✿.*`.°`,✿.*`,✿.* `,✿ `,✿.*`,✿.*`,✿.,✿.*`,✿.*`,✿.*’,✿.*`✿,
``,✿.*`.°`,✿.*`,✿.* `,✿.*`,°*`’.*`,✿.*✿
 `,✿.*`,✿.*`,✿.,✿.*`,✿.*`,✿.*’,✿.*`,✿
``,✿.*`.°`,✿.*`,✿.* `,✿.*`,°*`’ .*`,✿.*✿
`,✿.*`,✿.*`,✿.,✿.*`,✿.*`,✿.*’,✿.*`,✿

Answer (score 2):

Hint:$\dfrac{(n+1)^2}{n(n+2)}=1+\dfrac{1}{n(n+2)}$ and $\log(1+x)=x+O(x^2)$.

Comment: At the OP, if the big oh notation is unfamiliar, then this hint helps set up the limit comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

I only want to comment, is you forget to put a number 2, so you get infinite. If :
$$
S = \sum\limits _{n=1}^{\infty}\ln\left(\frac{\left(n+1\right)^{2}}{n\left(n+2\right)}\right)
$$
and 
$$
\ln({(n+1)^2 \over { n (n+2)}}) = 2\ln(n+1)-\ln(n)-\ln(n+2)
$$
rearranging, then we have this sume
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-\ln 1 & 2\ln2 & -\ln3 & & & \\
 & -\ln2 & 2\ln3 & -\ln4 & \\
 & & -\ln3 & 2\ln4 & -\ln5 \\
 & & & -\ln4 & 2\ln5 & ... \\...
\end{bmatrix}
$$
then, we can cancel every column ... staying with :
$$
S = \lim_{n \to \infty} ({-\ln1 + \ln2 +\ln n -\ln(n+1))} = \lim_{n \to \infty} {(\ln2 + \ln(n/n+1))} = \ln2 + 0 = \ln2
$$